# Rails 5: Error with spring when run devise:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying make a API with Rails

Ruby version: ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]
Rails version: Rails 5.2.4.1

I added the devise gem to the gemfile and ran the bundle, without errors. When I tried to run `$ rails generate devise: install`, this error occurred:

```
/home/isaac/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `ensure in preload': undefined method `application' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)
        from /home/isaac/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:126:in `preload'
        from /home/isaac/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
        from /home/isaac/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
        from /home/isaac/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
        from /home/isaac/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
        from /home/isaac/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/isaac/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from /home/isaac/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the spring server by using the following commands:

`bin/spring stop`

`bin/spring start`